# How to install fastclick with ember-cli?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've got an ember-cli project. I've used bower to install fastclick and have added it to my brocfile.

Now I'm trying to initialise it. In my `app.js` file I've added:

```
import FastClick from 'bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick';
```

But this gives me an error in the console: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined". The inspector shows the following generated code:

```
["ember","ember/resolver","ember/load-initializers","bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick","exports"],
function(__dependency1__, __dependency2__, __dependency3__, __dependency4__, __exports__) {
"use strict";
 var Ember = __dependency1__["default"];
 var Resolver = __dependency2__["default"];
 var loadInitializers = __dependency3__["default"];
 var FastClick = __dependency4__["default"];      # chrome highlights this line
```

I assume the problem is that fastclick isn't compatible with the ES6 loader that ember-cli uses. I don't have requirejs, so how can I install fastclick into my project? Docs are at https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick.

I've also tried adding this to index.html, but it doesn't have any effect when I build an iOS app:

```
  $(function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
  });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Ember-cli v0.0.42

Install fastclick with `bower`

```
bower install fastclick --save
```

In your Brocfile.js, add the following above `module.exports = app.toTree();`

```
app.import('bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js');
```

Then in your `app.js` you can add

```
var App = Ember.Application.extend({
  ...
  ready: function(){
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
  }
});
```

You'll also need to add `"FastClick":true` to your `.jshintrc` file's predefs, to prevent it from complaining. More info in the docs about [Managing Dependencies](http://www.ember-cli.com/#managing-dependencies).

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [ember-cli-fastclick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-fastclick) :)

Answer (score 0):

OK the jquery version didn't work, but putting the following in my `index.html` file did:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
}, false);
```